# Proof of Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, convex-optimization

The Hoeffding's inequality is $P(S_n - E[S_n] \geq \epsilon) \leq e^{-2\epsilon^2/k'}$, where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, $X_i$'s are independent bounded random variables, and $k'$ depends on the random variables.
In the proof of Hoeffding's inequality, an optimization problem of the form is solved:
$$\min_{s} \ \ e^{-s\epsilon}e^{ks^2}$$ subject to $s > 0$, to obtain a tight upper bound (which in turn yields the Hoeffding's inequality). 
It turns out that $s = \epsilon/2k$ is the value that obtains the Hoeffding's inequality. I don't see how.

EDIT: Note that $k > 0, \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I see that the problem is convex. I hope I'm have not misinterpreted the way $s$ is found to tighten the bound.

Comment: Could you write up the proof or include a link to it somewhere?  It would then be helpful if you could point exactly to the place in the proof where you are having trouble.

Comment: Since $f(s)=e^{ks^2-s\epsilon}$ has derivative $f'(s)=(2ks-\epsilon) e^{ks^2-s\epsilon}$,
which is negative for $s<\epsilon/2k$ and positive for $s>\epsilon/2k$, the minumum is attained at $s=\epsilon/2k$. Is that what's causing you trouble, or is it something else later on that you haven't told us about?

Comment: Yes, I was making a silly mistake. I think that's it. However, even for the function to be convex, we need something $s >= \epsilon/2k$ I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\exp$ is monotone increasing, your problem is equivalent to minimizing the quadratic $ks^2 - \epsilon s = k(s - \epsilon/2k)^2 - \epsilon^2/4k$.